# Looping an FLV file won't work with any AS3 code

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flv

So I'm facing a problem for the past 2 days, have tried every possible code snippet to force the .flv file to loop in the .swf file.

Here is the current code:

```
 import fl.video.VideoEvent;

 atropos.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, videoFinished);
 function videoFinished(event:Event){
         atropos.play();
 };
```

And the html:

```
            <param name="movie" value="atropos.swf" />
            <param name="quality" value="best" />
            <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
            <param name="play" value="true" />
            <param name="loop" value="true" />
            <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
            <param name="scale" value="showall" />
            <param name="menu" value="false" />
            <param name="devicefont" value="false" />
            <param name="salign" value="" />
            <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
```

It compiles everything with no errors but still the .swf file isn't looping. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could tell us how do you play your video, using a video component or `NetStream` ... ? What's `atropos` exactly ?

Comment: Hey, I've imported the .flv file to Adobe Flash using the "Import" function (from a web URL). Atropos is an animated character that our animator has exported from After Effects.

Answer (score 0):

Using the "Import" function (from a web URL) to import a video to your project, Flash will insert a [`FLVPlayback`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/video/FLVPlayback.html) component to play that video. And to replay your video you can use the `Event.COMPLETE` attached to your player like this :

```
// player is the FLVPlayback component inserted in the stage
var player:FLVPlayback;  
    player.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, function(e:Event){
        player.play();
    })
```

Hope that can help.